# Component OutlinedInput with param "notched" and component InputLabel with param "shrim" does not work correctly in Material UI 5.15.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, jsx

I have a very specific problem.. In `Material UI 5.15.2` I have my own component built to display `InputLabel` and `OutlinedInput` based on certain conditions.. In the example below, I pass a few parameters to tell my own component what to do:

- `type` param to switch the type of the field (in the case it will be `text` or `date`)
- `topLabel` param to make the label shrum or not - it will add `shrim={true}` to the `InputLabel` component and `notched={true}` to the `OutlinedInput` component..
  This is because input with `type="data"` should show the label as `shrim` and other input with `type="text"` should only use `shrim` when focusing/typing as the default behavior of the MUI component..

I tried using `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: !!topLabel }}` param for the `InputLabel` component and `InputProps={{ notched: !!topLabel }}` param for the `OutlinedInput` component, but these types of attempts failed.

Is there a way to achieve the result..?

Code:

```
export const TextFieldInput = ({ label, name, type = "text", topLabel = false, value }) => {
  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel shrink={!!topLabel}>
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput 
        label={label}
        name={name}
        notched={!!topLabel}
        type={type}
        value={value}
      />
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

and then somewhere in the layout call to the own component

```
import { TextFieldInput } from "@/components/TextFieldInput";

export const Form = ({ values }) => {
  return (
    <form>
      <TextFieldInput label="Surname" name="surname" type="text" topLabel={false} value={values["surname"]} />
      <TextFieldInput label="Date of birth" name="dob" type="date" topLabel={true} value={values["dob"]} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

At this stage of development the field with `type="date"` is displaying correct label but the field with `type="text"` is not working as should.

The expected result should be as follow:

- the `surname` field should display the label as placeholder and then when interacting the label should go to the top
- the `dob` field should not display the label as placeholder because the date field has own placeholder to show date pattern

Please see the screenshot to understand the goal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty amazing solution to this problem.. It's worth knowing if someone needs something similar..

To achieve the goal, we need to use the internal `state` (hook `useState`) with initial value based on the condition (`useState(type === "date")` in my case), and then use the state value to set the `notched` and `shrink` values..

For this to work, we need to use a state method (`setShrink` in my case) and set the correct state when using one of the 3 input component events::

- `onBlur`
- `onChange`
- `onFocus`

The beauty of this solution is even greater - we do not need additional props to achieve it, because we can build the condition using only the `type` of input field.

The code below shows what it should look like:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const TextFieldInput = ({ label, name, type = "text", value }) => {
  const [shrink, setShrink] = useState(type === "date"); // <-- state

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel shrink={shrink}>
        {label}
      </InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput 
        label={label}
        name={name}
        notched={shrink}
        onBlur={e => setShrink(!!e.target.value || type === "date")}
        onFocus={e => setShrink(true)}
        onChange={e => setShrink(!!e.target.value)}
        type={type}
        value={value}
      />
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```